# How did Wanda know that Bruce is Hulk?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-age-of-ultron

In *Avengers: Age of Ultron*, Wanda influences Avengers' consciousness.

> Pietro Maximoff: What can I do?
>
> Wanda Maximoff: Ah, it hurts.
>
> Pietro Maximoff: I'm gonna kill him. I'll be right back.
>
> Wanda Maximoff: No. I'm over it. I want...I want to finish the plan.
>   [looking at the Quinjet where Banner is waiting] I want the big one.
>   [after Stark corners Ultron]

How did she know that Bruce is Hulk? I mean, she saw him only as Hulk, and not as Bruce Banner.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because Bruce Banner being Hulk is not a secret identity and nobody have to do any maths to prove it. He doesn't dress up as Spider-Man in hiding but he just transforms in front of everyone.

So Wanda knowing it doesn't look like a big thing and remember they have been trained by Hydra to be used against Avengers so they must have done basic homework.

Comment: Your second point is definitely valid. However, while things may work differently in the MCU from the comics, I don't believe anyone has ever recognized Bruce based on having seen the Hulk. In fact, for the first few years (publication time, not in-universe time) of his existence, no one knew Banner was the Hulk but Rick Jones; even those who'd known Banner for a good while and had seen the Hulk up close, like Betsy and Thunderbolt Ross. People only started recognizing Banner as a threat once his situation was made public - and recognized him because Banner's picture was circulated.